# React-native Trim Video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video-editing

Is there any way to **trim captured video** ?
I can't find any library for that.

**My environment:**

- React-Native version: 0.36
- OS: MacOS
- Platform: Android and iOS

Thanks !.

Comment: @ZeRubeus all files deleted there

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since i can't find ready library for my issue, then i write my own library

https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing

Here is it. Currenlty it's working only for iOS. In the future I'll write it for android

Comment: Is this version is now available for Android?

Comment: Yes @VishalSenjaliya

Comment: Hey, @ShahenHovhannisyan thanks for this awesome library. Do you still working on it to update for react-native higher versions?

Comment: Thank you @AnuragShrivastava. Currently, the library is maintained by the community. In case of PR, I'll review/merge/release ASAP